# Discerning pointers and memory allocation

Tags: c, memory, pointers

What are the memory allocations (if there are any) for `p`, `*p` and `**p` and where they are when I write `char **p = NULL` ?

Comment: but i guess that when I write char *p = NULL then 4 bytes of memory (in 32 bit addressable system) is allocated in the stack if this is a local variable and in the region of global variables if this is a global variable.

Answer (score 4):

The size of `p` depends on its type.  The size of `*p` and `**p` (and `***p`, `**********p`, etc.) is the size of a pointer:  typically either 4 or 8 bytes depending on whether you're using a 32-bit or 64-bit system.

When you write `char **p = NULL`, you're not allocating any additional memory beyond what `char **p` would give you.  You're just initializing the variable's place in memory with a value, rather than leaving it uninitialized.

As for *where* they are, it depends on the context.  If those are local variables within a function, they'll be allocated on the stack when the function is called.  If they're global variables, they'll be given locations in the program's data segment.  If they're members of a `struct`, then it depends on where you declare variables of the structure type.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are stored on stack, if not static/global. There is no heap memory allocation here. It's just (non-valid) memory addresses.

Comment: and is the same valid for memories of p and *p too?

Comment: Basically any variable declared within function is auto-allocated on stack, if not excpicitly specified otherwise. If you have `int p`, it's integer stored on stack. If you have `int *p`, it's invalid pointer to integer, pointing to random location (if not in debug build), unless you manually assign where is should point to.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `char **p = NULL;`, `p` is going to be either a local variable (in most cases, on the stack, if it's defined inside a function), or a global variable (in most cases neither on the stack nor in the heap (from where `malloc()` allocates memory), if it's defined outside of all functions).

`*p`'s location is undefined because you cannot legally dereference a NULL pointer.

The same holds for `**p` because you'd first need to derefence `p`, which is illegal.

And so on.